# Laravel Authentication With External User Table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I made a Laravel based web app that uses it's default auth methods. It has some slight modifications that suit my needs, like role management, but that is not the issue here.

The client I'm working for has an existing PHP based app/website which already has it's own custom user auth table/db.

The main problem here is - **he would like to log in to the Laravel site using his session data from the old site, without authenticating twice.**

Is there any way to achieve this and if yes, how could it eventually be solved?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Where are the session stored in the existing website? Is it saved in the database?

Comment: I think the session data is stored on the servers file system. I should also mention the sites are on different servers.

Comment: Is that table in the same database or is it in another database?

Comment: No. Completely different servers, also different database server.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue. My problem was a little simpler — all I cared about was having a logged-in-session, actual user profile or permissions weren’t necessary — but anyway this should get you on the right path.

I created a file called index_laravel.php, and used .htaccess to route requests to this instead of index.php.

```
<?php
$path = "../../bootstrap/";
require($path . 'autoload.php');
$app = require_once($path . 'app.php');
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
if( !$app['auth']->check() ) {
    echo('Please login through [blah blah whatever].');
    // or do a header("location:…") here
} else {
    require_once('index.php');
}
```